# Call javascript method in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a simple page in  html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script >
function submit() {
alert('aa');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "form.html" method = "POST">
Label<inpt type = "text"></br>
Label2<inpt type = "text"></br>
Label3<inpt type = "text"></br>
Label4<inpt type = "text"></br>
Label5<inpt type = "text"></br>
<button type="button" id="no" onclick="submit();">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to use function submit to show AlertDialog in android.
This is my code:

```
final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface
= new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
formWebView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "no");
formWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
formWebView.loadUrl(url);
formWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

and MyJavaScriptInterface:

```
public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
          Context mContext;

             MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
                 mContext = c;
             }

             public void submitForm(){
                  AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
                  = new AlertDialog.Builder(AmmsFormsWebViewActivity.this);
                  myDialog.setTitle("DANGER2!");
                  myDialog.setMessage("You can do what you want2!");
                  myDialog.setPositiveButton("ON", null);
                  myDialog.show();
             }

         }
```

but doesn't work. Where I have a bug? I want to chceck if submit() method is use from webview I want to show dialog in android.

Comment: Are you getting any error ? If so, post the stack trace. Also see if javascript is enabled in your browser options .

Comment: use mcontext instead of AmmsFormsWebViewActivity.this in your MyJavaScriptInterface class file. like  AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
                  = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);

Comment: I don't get any error. Everything is ok, but when I click on button I don't see Alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "name" of your JS interface is `no` when you add the interface to your webview, and the method in your JS interface is `submitForm()`, the javascript should call `no.submitForm();` for the interface to catch it.